# Controlling the order in which files are put into an array

Tags: bash, mutt, array

I have a script that grabs a bunch of time-stamped files and puts them into an array to be processed by Mutt and emailed to me. My problem is that the files are just randomly placed into the array and, as such, get emailed to me in a disordered mess. Is there a way to control the order in which these files are placed into the array? I would like them to be ordered by date. 
Here is the script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%F)
recipients="myEmail@domain.com"
body="Found these files:"
mapfile -t files < <(find /my/directory -name '*.jpg' -newermt '-15 seconds' -not -newermt '-2 seconds')

if [ -z "$files" ]; then
body="No files were found"
echo "$body" | mutt -s "Error on $TODAY" $recipients
fi

echo "$body" | mutt -s "Files found on $date" -a "${files[@]}" -- $recipients
echo "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: What order do you want? Tried using a `| sort` with the `find` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zsh` instead of `bash`, where you can define the sorting (by name by default):

```
files=(/my/directory/**/*.jpg(.NDms+2ms-15))
```

That will also avoid problems with file names containing newline characters (`bash-4.4`'s `mapfile` supports `-d ''` that can be used with `find -print0` though).

To sort (**o**rder) by **m**odification time:

```
files=(/my/directory/**/*.jpg(.NDms+2ms-15om))
```

To get a similar (by name) order with GNU `find` and GNU `sort`:

```
find /my/directory -name '*.jpg' \
                   -type f \
                   -newermt '-15 seconds' \
                   ! -newermt '-2 seconds' \
                   -print0 |
  sort -zt/ -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6 -k7,7 -k8,8 \
            -k9,9 -k10,10 -k11,11 -k12,12 -k13,13 -k14,14
```

For modification time order:

```
find /my/directory -name '*.jpg' \
                   -type f \
                   -newermt '-15 seconds' \
                   ! -newermt '-2 seconds' \
                   -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
  sort -zn |
  sed -z 's/[^:]*://#'
```

Add `| tr '\0' '\n'` to store in a bash *scalar* (not array) variable or to use with `readarray`/`mapfile` without `-d ''` (split on newline, in which case you might as well do the whole thing on newline delimited records instead of NUL delimited records).

Or use `readarray -d '' array < <(find...)` with bash 4.4 or above or in `zsh`, use `array=(${(0)"$(find...)"})`.

Comment: Using find and sort works, although only one file gets sent.

Comment: I am using bash 3.2

Comment: @Yllier123, add `| tr '\0' '\n'` to store in a bash variable or to use with readarray without `-d ''` (to split on newlines).

Comment: That solved it. Thank you very much for your time :)